# NameError: name 'N' is not defined

Tags: python

The goal is to find a solution to the [dashatize it](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58223370aef9fc03fd000071) challenge on codewards

> If n is an integer, Return a string with dash'-'marks before and after each odd integer, but do not begin or end the string with a dash mark. If n is negative, then the negative sign should be removed.
> If n is not an integer, return the string "NaN".

This is the code I wrote where it supposed to output as below:

> dashatize(6815) -> '68-1-5'

```
def dashatize(n):
    make_string = str(n)
    make_list = list(make_string.strip())
    make_list_int = [eval(i) for i in make_list]
    test = []
    result = []
    final_result_2 = None
    make_list_int.append(1)
    
    if n == None:
        pass
    
    else:
        for number in make_list_int:
            positions_odd_or_even = []
            for a in range(len(test)):
                if test[a] == "odd":
                    positions_odd_or_even.append(a)

            if (number % 2) == 0: 
                test.append("even")
                position = make_list_int.index(number)
                kesel = make_list_int[position] + make_list_int[position+1]
                if (kesel % 2) > 0:
                    result.insert(position+1, str(number) + "-")
                if (kesel % 2) == 0:
                    result.insert(position, str(number))
            if (number % 2) >= 1:
                test.append("odd")
                position = make_list_int.index(number)
                result.insert(position+1, str(number) + "-")

        final_result_1 = ''.join(result)
        final_result_2 = final_result_1[:-3]

    return final_result_2
```

It went well until I did the attempt. It shows that it passed all the test but didn't know why an error occured.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/default/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(dashatize(None),"None", "Should return None");
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 4, in dashatize
    make_list_int = [eval(i) for i in make_list]
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    make_list_int = [eval(i) for i in make_list]
                     ^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'N' is not defined
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What is in the `n` variable? I assume some string with code? `list(make_string.strip())` creates a list where each element is a letter of the `make_string`. So `eval(i)` processes a string with one character, something like `eval('N')`. So what does one line of Python that states `N` should do, well raise `NameError` because `N` is indeed undefined.

Comment: And of course you shouldn't use `eval` when you really want `int`. Where do they teach things like this? Please read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: Your make_list list is a list of characters one of which is 'N'

Comment: Eval is generally bad practice, there is almost never any need to use it

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych No, it doesn't do `eval('N')`, but `eval(N)`.

Comment: @Matthias it is `eval(i)`, how can it be `eval(N)`. `i` here is a string, so it is `eval('N')`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych  str(None) leads to "None" and for loop tries to eval each element of ["N", "o", "n", "e"]

Comment: And the error comes from tests that passes that None ..  This looks so messy

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you should only work with integers. The eval function raises an error when working with a string. I would check if the parameter is a number

```
def dashatize(n):

    if not n.isdigit():
        return None

    make_string = str(n)
    make_list = list(make_string.strip())
    make_list_int = [eval(i) for i in make_list]
    test = []
    result = []
    final_result_2 = None
    make_list_int.append(1)
    
    if n == None:
        pass
    
    else:
        for number in make_list_int:
            positions_odd_or_even = []
            for a in range(len(test)):
                if test[a] == "odd":
                    positions_odd_or_even.append(a)

            if (number % 2) == 0: 
                test.append("even")
                position = make_list_int.index(number)
                kesel = make_list_int[position] + make_list_int[position+1]
                if (kesel % 2) > 0:
                    result.insert(position+1, str(number) + "-")
                if (kesel % 2) == 0:
                    result.insert(position, str(number))
            if (number % 2) >= 1:
                test.append("odd")
                position = make_list_int.index(number)
                result.insert(position+1, str(number) + "-")

        final_result_1 = ''.join(result)
        final_result_2 = final_result_1[:-3]

    return final_result_2
print(dashatize('6815'))
print(dashatize('N'))
print(dashatize('1233123'))
```